# Can i run .exe file by passing blob storage as an input parameter and output parament using ADF in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-custom-providers

I'm fairly new to the Azure environment. I want to execute an .exe file by passing blob storage as an input and output parameter.

The .exe is a third party. It takes a file as an input and provides another file as an output.

Not sure if this can be achievable using azure ADF.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to deploy an azure function that includes your exe - gets the input parameters, calls the exe, get the output and write it to blob storage which can then be read from ADF.

It isn't too much work but the key part is getting the exe to run somewhere and a function is the simplest I think.

To draw out the process it would look something like:

- ADF Copies the file from the source, writes it to blob storage
- Call the Azure Function and pass in the path to the new file
- The function downloads the file locally, calls the exe passing in the local file path
- The exe reads the input, writes the output file locally to the function
- The function reads the output file, writes it back to blob storage
- The function returns the path to the output file in blob storage

Ed

Comment: the input files is in ADL so how can i pass that file as an parameter to function if we go with that approch

Comment: You will need to write the file somewhere as intermediate storage like blob storage etc

Comment: okk but sorry i am still not able to understand how can i pass the input parameter( file on the blob storage) to the function app every next day i am going to get the new file on the blob storage that exe will process that file and again provide another file as an output